# Null / empty string checking: CPU overhead

Tags: c++, null, cpu-usage, cstring, overhead

I have this function that will print a 2D text in `OpenGL`

```
void Text2D::printText(const BMfont &font, const char *text, const PenList &pen_list);
```

I have several applications(games) that uses this a lot, but I never passed an empty string to it **but now**. Most of the the `string` I used is the `std::string::c_str()`.

And also, I have these variants for null checking (or empty string checking).

```
    if (text[0] == '\0') return; // # 1
    if (text == '\0') return;  //   # 2
    if (text == nullptr) return; // # 3
```

This will be the first instruction to be executed upon calling the function `Text2D::printText()`

All of those check causes a CPU usage of about 50% except for `# 1`. I'm pretty sure it is and this is very odd to me.

What's the difference between those 3? I thought `# 1` and `# 2` are the same and I thought the `# 3` will convert the `nullptr` to `'\0'`? Why `# 2` and `# 3` cost too much CPU usage? What is the proper and safe way to check for an empty `C-string`?

Comment: I'm not sure what tool is reporting this to you, but the tool's got to be wrong. Following a pointer and testing something is going to be slower than just testing something.

Comment: @BillyONeal Didn't get it. I used `taskmgr.exe` of `Windows XP` as tool for CPU usage check.

Comment: `taskmgr` is not accurate enough for a 1 or 2 instruction difference. Something else is going on here. (e.g. as I said below, if the answer "the string is empty" allows you to skip a bunch of expensive code, the first one checks for the string being empty, the second two check for null pointers. The time difference would be from the block of expensive code, not this test.)

Comment: @BillyONeal ahm, I render the 2D text in `glfw3` and I know that FPS is locked to 60. But why does it happen that CPU usage accumulates to 50 percent?

Comment: @EdS. I include those code on at a time, so all of them will not execute at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way (1) (the check alone, not execution after that) can be faster than (2) and (3). It is logical to think that following the pointer would take more cycles than just checking the address value.

Check for example the code generated for x86.

```
if (text == '\0') return -1;  //   # 2
```

01028C6E  cmp         dword ptr [text],0
01028C72  jne         printText+29h (01028C79h)
01028C74  or          eax,0FFFFFFFFh
01028C77  jmp         printText+4Bh (01028C9Bh)

```
if (text == nullptr) return 0; // # 3
```

01028C79  cmp         dword ptr [text],0
01028C7D  jne         printText+33h (01028C83h)
01028C7F  xor         eax,eax
01028C81  jmp         printText+4Bh (01028C9Bh)

```
  if (text[0] == '\0') return 1; // # 1
```

01028C83  mov         eax,1
01028C88  imul        eax,eax,0
01028C8B  mov         ecx,dword ptr [text]
01028C8E  movsx       edx,byte ptr [ecx+eax]
01028C92  test        edx,edx
01028C94  jne         printText+4Bh (01028C9Bh)
01028C96  mov         eax,1

Note that, you should not dereference the pointer without checking the pointer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Number 1 dereferences the pointer, numbers 2 and 3 do not. Therefore we would expect the first to take longer if the target of the pointer needs to be fetched from memory.

In general, tooling is very bad about telling you what's going on in microbenchmarks like this.

It should be noted that the first one goes into the string and checks if it is empty; the second two do not. Therefore, if this check is around some big complex piece of code, it is likely any speedup you're seeing is the result of skipping that block when the string is empty (not only when the pointer is null), rather than anything to do with this test.

If you want to consider null to be the same as empty, then you need both tests:

```
if (str == nullptr || str[0] == '\0') {
    // String is empty
}
```

because `str[0]` is undefined if `str` is nullptr.

Comment: But why does my CPU runs at 50% even `glfw3` locks the framerate at 60fps and if the string is not null or is not empty, it runs smoothly(I mean, about 0% - 1%) ??